# Can I Revoke Nodejs Core C++ Module in Local Module?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

As we know in Nodejs, javascript core module (under lib/ folder) uses `process.binding()` to bind C++ code which is under src/ folder. Is there any way I can do to bind c++ core module code which under src/ folder to my local module(not core module)? In conclusion, I want my application to directly bind with my local C++ core module bypassing js core module. Is that possible?